# Could not fetch URL installing python packages installation

Tags: python, installation, pip

I am trying to install some packages for python from the command prompt, but it shows me the following issue, I set the proxy in order to solve the issue with the firewall. but the issue is still there. Before I set the proxy I could not install any packages after that I could install numpy but nothing else.
[Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/scipy/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/scipy/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1123)'))) - skipping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQlnc.png)

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes if you use Python 2 and Python 3 on your computer, pip will default to Python 2. As of January 1, 2021, [Python 2 is no longer supported](https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/). Therefore, a lot of packages are no longer supported on Python 2. Try the following:

```
pip3 install scipy
```

pip3 always operates on the Python3 environment only, as pip2 does with Python2.

Comment: thank you very much for answering. the problem was actually when setting the proxy, instead of using https I had to use http.
Thanks a lot though!